# Cannot locate cabal installed packages

Tags: macos, haskell, package, cabal, ghc-pkg

I am at a loss. I use OS X 10.8.2.

The only reference I can find is this:

- > 4.1 I just installed packages, but now the packages are not found`
- > This happens when you install a package globally, and the previous
  >   packages were installed locally. Note that cabal-install install
  >   locally by default and the "runhaskell Setup" commands install
  >   globally by default.

cabal is set to install locally by default. I have not changed this. Haskell was installed globally.

```
$ cabal install pointfree
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring pointfree-1.0.4.3...
Building pointfree-1.0.4.3...
Preprocessing executable 'pointfree' for pointfree-1.0.4.3...
[1 of 7] Compiling Plugin.Pl.Common ( Plugin/Pl/Common.hs, dist/build/pointfree/pointfree-tmp/Plugin/Pl/Common.o )
[2 of 7] Compiling Plugin.Pl.Parser ( Plugin/Pl/Parser.hs, dist/build/pointfree/pointfree-tmp/Plugin/Pl/Parser.o )
[3 of 7] Compiling Plugin.Pl.PrettyPrinter ( Plugin/Pl/PrettyPrinter.hs, dist/build/pointfree/pointfree-tmp/Plugin/Pl/PrettyPrinter.o )
[4 of 7] Compiling Plugin.Pl.Transform ( Plugin/Pl/Transform.hs, dist/build/pointfree/pointfree-tmp/Plugin/Pl/Transform.o )
[5 of 7] Compiling Plugin.Pl.Rules  ( Plugin/Pl/Rules.hs, dist/build/pointfree/pointfree-tmp/Plugin/Pl/Rules.o )
[6 of 7] Compiling Plugin.Pl.Optimize ( Plugin/Pl/Optimize.hs, dist/build/pointfree/pointfree-tmp/Plugin/Pl/Optimize.o )
[7 of 7] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, dist/build/pointfree/pointfree-tmp/Main.o )
Linking dist/build/pointfree/pointfree ...
Warning: No documentation was generated as this package does not contain a
library. Perhaps you want to use the --executables flag.
Installing executable(s) in
/Users/beoliver/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib/pointfree-1.0.4.3/bin
Installed pointfree-1.0.4.3
Updating documentation index /Users/beoliver/Library/Haskell/doc/index.html

$ cat ~/.bash_profile
export PATH="$HOME/Library/Haskell/bin:$PATH"


$ ls -l ~/Library/Haskell/bin/
total 24
lrwxr-xr-x  1 beoliver  staff  49 Dec 28 16:06 cabal -> ../ghc-7.4.2/lib/cabal-install-1.16.0.2/bin/cabal
lrwxr-xr-x  1 beoliver  staff  48 Dec 28 19:52 pointfree -> ../ghc-7.4.2/lib/pointfree-1.0.4.3/bin/pointfree
-rw-r--r--  1 beoliver  staff  66 Dec 28 19:53 x
```

The x is odd...

```
$ cat ~/Library/Haskell/bin/x
(line 1, column 5):
unexpected "+"
expecting space or simple term
```

hmm

I check `ghc-pkg list` but it is not there. So see if it with the `user` packages.

```
$ ls ~/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib/
Cabal-1.16.0.3      cabal-install-1.16.0.2  pointfree-1.0.4.3

$ file pointfree-1.0.4.3/bin/pointfree 
pointfree-1.0.4.3/bin/pointfree: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

$ ghc-pkg list --user
/Users/beoliver/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-7.4.2/package.conf.d
   Cabal-1.16.0.3
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0.3 of the Cabal library
```

Am I missing a flag here? do i still need to build it?

```
$ ghc-pkg check
Warning: haddock-interfaces: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib/haskell-platform-2012.4.0.0/doc/html/haskell-platform.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-html: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib/haskell-platform-2012.4.0.0/doc/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
Warning: haddock-interfaces: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib/GLUT-2.1.2.1/doc/html/GLUT.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I check `ghc-pkg list` but it is not there.

`ghc-pkg` only knows and cares about installed libraries. `pointfree` is an executable without accompanying library, so `ghc-pkg` doesn't know about it.

Since `$HOME/Library/Haskell/bin` is in your `PATH`, and the executable is linked to there, you can simply run it from the command line

```
$ pointfree "\f x y -> f y x"
flip
```

(or something like that, it's been a long time since I played with pointfree).

> the x is odd...

That looks like a parse error message from `parsec`. I have no idea what may have written it to that file, though.

```
$ ghc-pkg check
Warning: haddock-interfaces: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib/haskell-platform-2012.4.0.0/doc/html/haskell-platform.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-html: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib/haskell-platform-2012.4.0.0/doc/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
Warning: haddock-interfaces: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib/GLUT-2.1.2.1/doc/html/GLUT.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
```

Something seems to have trampled on your haddocks, or they weren't properly installed from the beginning. That *may* indicate an actual problem, but you can probably ignore it if you don't want local documentation.

Comment: +1 as well. I had tried $ pointfree /x ... but did not think to put it in "quotes"! Great stuff! thank you. I'll go ahead and delete the random file as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found my cabal package binaries in `~/.cabal/bin/`.